# Getting lat, long from iphone UDID only ...?

Tags: iphone

how can i get lat,long information from my device UDID only ???

not using CoreLocation fromework , using device UDID only...!!!

Comment: How would a UDID give any kind of location information? It'd be like me telling you my real name and you somehow figuring out where I'm typing this from right now.

Comment: You typed it from a PC. Did I won?

Comment: then How, when connected to internet some illegal iphone & macs are traced by Apple

Comment: @justSid: that so obvious !! You won. :)

Comment: but here question is like how you know my pc mac address ? :)

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible.

Comment: there should be some way directly or indirectly....!!! UDID is  bit like as IMEI number and we know that using IMEI number mobile are possible to trace...!! So whats a problem with UDID ???

Comment: The IMEI can only be traced when the phone connects to the mobile operator through one of the many base stations around the world. The positions of the base station is known, so you can tell from that where the user _could_ be. However, the IMEI itself isn't traceable, just like the UDID.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, the UDID is just a unique identifier for the device.  It doesn't change no matter where you go.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm sure AT&T has some capability to track a device merely by UDID, there is no API for this and it is completely impossible.

Comment: thats why i told that direct or indirect way  to track device.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Apple has a private database containing UDID to IMEI mappings?  And the cell towers know the IMEI numbers of any devices nearby and connected?

If you are not Apple and the cellular provider, you won't have this hypothetical data.